# Php/MySQL: Hours reported, hourly rate

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following tables (simplified):

```
   hours               hour_rates
 - user_id            - user_id
 - date               - date
 - hours              - hourly_rate
```

Hours table example:

```
1 - 2012-03-19 - 8
```

This means that user with id=1, at 2012-03-19 worked 8 hours in total.

The hourly rate for a person can change in time, so I have the second table:

hour_rates table  Example

```
1 - 2011-12-01 - 20
1 - 2011-12-20 - 25
```

So for user with id=1, we set a hourly rate of 20$ at 2011-12-01.
We changed his hourly rate at 2011-12-20, to 25$.

What I want is, to calculate how much I have to pay for a given user (ex. id=1) for a given period (ex. 2012-01-01 -> 2012-02-01).

Can I calculate this simply mysql side?
If not, how to do it in an efficient way?

Comment: why would you wanna do that on mysql side - if you don't need to use the result in mysql query you should do the calculation in your code; otherwise use stored procedures/functions

Comment: I'd suggest working this a little differently, I'd add the ID of the hourly rate being used in the `hours` table when you make an entry, it'd simplify everything.

Comment: @BenGriffiths This can be a good alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In hour_rates table you should have two dates: start_date and end_date this means from start_date to end_date the emplyer has been paid x$ per hour.

Then use the same query proposed by bpgergo modified like this:

```
   select sum(h.hours * hr.hourly_rate) as pay
   from hours h, hour_rates hr
   where h.user_id = :user_id --here you will set the user id parameter
   and h.user_id = hr.user_id and (h.date BETWEEN hr.start_date AND hr.end_date 
   and h.date between STR_TO_DATE('01,1,2012','%d,%m,%Y') and STR_TO_DATE('01,1,2011','%d,%m,%Y')
```

Comment: boy, that is way much too complicated, in my sense... just use one table, in each entry put the user_id, the date, the hours worked and the hourly_rate.. if there are different hourly rates on one day, you just have more entries with the same date...

Comment: Sure this is an easier solution for the calculation you need to do. But for other kind of query your solution could be poor design, for example. Image you want to display the history of the employee reward per hour. For example from 2011-01-01 to 2011-06-01 50$ per hour the from 2011-06-02 60$ per hour and so on... with you new table this calculation won't be so easy. However it depends on what kind of calculation you have to do!

Comment: no, ab_dev86, you are wrong sorry, it is exactly upside down! my table design would make that very easy, in fact. You have the whole working history with the exact hourly_rate for each day worked, and the amount of hours. Furthermore, concerning performance it is much much faster and not complex...

Comment: I'am sospicius abuot a query like this: "Tell me when an employee had an increase or decrease in per hour reward". How would it be this query in your new table layout?

Comment: I guess you are missing the requirements, ab_dev86... have you heard about database normalization? having two tables with identical entries will kill you... however, it is very easy: SELECT date, hours, hourly_rate FROM hours WHERE user_id=$user_id ORDER BY date; and while read from database { check if row[hourly_rate] increased or decreased, if yes echo row[date] }

Answer (score 1):

> Can I calculate this simply mysql side?

Yes, this is the SQL

```
select sum(outer_h.hours * 
  (select inner_hr.hourly_rate 
    from hour_rates inner_hr
    where inner_hr.user_id = outer_h.user_id
    and inner_hr.date >= outer_h.date
    order by inner_hr.date asc
    limit 1)
) as pay
  from hours outer_h
  where outer_h.user_id = :user_id --here you will set the user id parameter
  and outer_h.date between STR_TO_DATE('01,1,2012','%d,%m,%Y') and STR_TO_DATE('01,1,2011','%d,%m,%Y')
```

Comment: Looks like a very pretty query. The only point I'am sospicius abuot is that you use this join condition and h.date = hr.date but hr.date means that from this date the employ has this now price per hour. Suppose hr.date is = 2012-01-01 you want to calcute the amount to pay to employ for the day 2012-01-02 but the and condition fails and no result is returned by the query. I'm not sure of that, the query should be tested...

Comment: hmm... You're absolutely right, I was not careful enough, just glanced through the question and wrote a quick answer. Let me fix this.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: So, sorry but what do you need 2 tables for that? They are totally equal, if every day can have its own hourly_rate, you only need to store it like this:

> hours: user_id, date, hours, hourly_rate

e.g. 1 | 2012-03-19 | 8 | 25

You use

```
 SELECT user_id, date, hours, hourly_rate FROM hours WHERE (user_id=$var_of_user_id AND date ...)
```

and then multiply for each row hours*hourly_rate and add it to $sum, e.g.

```
while {...

$sum=$sum+($row['hours']*$row['hourly_rate']);

}
```

---

what does the hourly_rate depend on? probably you don't want to have the field date in the hour_rates table.

if hourly_rate is different for each job, you want to have only one table with user_id, start_date, end_date (or hours worked) and hourly_rate.

if hourly_rate depends only on user_id, then you want to have two tables:

> **hours**: user_id, start_date, end_date (or hours worked)
>
> **hourly_rate**: user_id, hourly_rate

and join the tables on user_id. If you already have a table users, you could store the hourly_rate there too, in the second case.

Then use php to simply multiply the hours worked with the hourly rate where user_id... etc.

Comment: a person's hourly rate can change in time, for the same task, and same project.

Comment: @Tamas Pap: but the hourly_rate is still fix I mean it cannot change after he worked one hour for 50USD, 2 weeks later you say: hey, you only get 30USD for what you did last week, right?

Answer (score 1):

This query should work:

```
SELECT SUM( h.hours*COALESCE(hr.hourly_rate,0) ) AS salary
FROM hours h
LEFT JOIN hour_rates hr
ON h.user_id = hr.user_id 
AND  hr.date = ( SELECT MAX(hd.date) FROM hour_rates hd
                 WHERE hd.user_id = h.user_id AND hd.date <= h.date )
WHERE h.user_id = 1
AND h.date BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-04-01'
```

The coalesce part is there just in case the hourly pay is not defined for a given user and date, you can put a default rate there instead of 0. Also make sure that every pair (user_id,date) in your hour_rates table is unique.